# Getting Error converting MS-Word to PDF using ABCpdf

Tags: abcpdf

I'm trying to convert a Doc file into a PDF usin ABCpdf:

```
            using (Doc objDoc = new Doc())
            using (XReadOptions xr = new XReadOptions())
            {
                xr.ReadModule = ReadModuleType.MSOffice;
                objDoc.Read(@"C:\Code\Website\App_Data\ContentRepository\0\6\10\test.doc", xr);
                objDoc.Save(@"C:\Code\Website\App_Data\ContentRepository\0\6\10\test.pdf");
                objDoc.Clear();
            }
```

I get the following exception

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1]
   System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) +14696197
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.WordApplication..ctor(Options bootOpts) +149
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.MSOfficeApplicationPool.GetWord() +140
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.MSOfficeApplicationPool.GetAppForFile(String path) +206
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.MSOfficeDetails.Importer.ImportImplExportFromApp(Doc doc, String path, XReadOptions opts) +208
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.Internal.MSOfficeDetails.Importer.Import(Doc doc, String path, XReadOptions opts) +239
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.XReadOptions.Read(Doc doc, String path, ReadModuleType module) +318
   WebSupergoo.ABCpdf8.XReadOptions.Read(Doc doc, String path) +68
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: What version of ABCpdf are you using? The latest is 9.1.1.8 https://www.nuget.org/packages/ABCpdf/

Comment: no its 8.1.2 updated to 9 and it solved it .. thnx